# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (1,), while fitting with lmfit

Tags: lmfit

I am trying to fit a formula using lmfit but I am getting error as mentioned above.
here is my data file [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=176ipjOz0M1d8gCar91HSc5Bc5n9eTL5o)

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import exp, loadtxt, pi, sqrt, sinh
from lmfit import Model


    k = 1.38e-23
    hcut = 1.0e-34
    e = 1.6e-19
    B = 6.15

    a = (2*(pi**2)*k)/(hcut*e*B)
    c = 2.12
    b = hcut/(2*pi*k)

    data = loadtxt('data.csv')
    x = data[:, 0]
    y = data[:, 1]
    z = math.sinh(0.5)
    z1 = math.sinh(a*9.1e-31)

    def LK(x, t, m):
       return (4*c*exp(-(a*m*b)/t))
    gmodel = Model(LK)
    result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, t=1e-10, m=1e-19)

    print(result.fit_report())

    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
    plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--', label='initial fit')
    plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-', label='best fit')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

I was trying this from a code already available here:https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html, but somehow it does not seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model function does not include `x`, and so will return a scalar value.    The fit will give up very easily.  FWIW `t=1e-10, m=1e-19` are terrible initial values, as they probably would push the function so far to zero that the fit would never move from those values.